# jQueryの特定のイベント時にvelocity.jsが動作しない

Tags: html, jquery

Velocity.js について質問です。
jQuery のクリックイベントのコールバック関数内に `velocity` を記述すると、

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).velocity is not a function

のエラーが起きます。

---

Web サイトで検索しましたが、原因がわかりません。
同様らしい質問も見つかりましたが、英語なのでいまいち意味が理解できません。
どなたか解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

---

ちなみに、 jQuery の `load` イベント内に同様の内容を記述すると正常に動作します。
**動作しないイベント:**

- `click`
- `hover`

**動作したイベント:**

- `load`

---

簡略化したソースコードを示します。

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js読み込み"></script>
        <script src='velocity.min.js読み込み'></script>
   </head>
<body>
<script src='javascript読み込み'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#object').velocity({translateY:'-=50'});
});
```

---

同様の問題と思われる Web サイトを記載します

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233146/javascript-script-loading-order-function-undefined
https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-velocityjs/issues/2

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: おそらくvelocityプラグインの読込実行完了前に該当機能を使おうとしているのだと思います。あるいは、何かの時に上書きしてしまったとか・

Comment: このサンプルは動作するでしょうか？ http://jsfiddle.net/6yfwp0zq/1/ 読み込み部分をhead内に移動して、スクリプトを別ファイルに切り出せば、提示されたコードと同じ構造になるはずですが、お手元でそのように編集していただくと問題が再現しますか？

Comment: お二人ともコメントありがとうございます。
＞unaristさん
指示通りコピーしてみましたが、動作せず、同じエラーが発生しました。
文法間違いの問題ではないようですので、問題を簡単にして少し調べてみます。